# List the namenode and datanodes of a cluster from any node?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

From any node in a Hadoop cluster, what is the command to

- identify the running namenode?
- identify all running datanodes?

I have looked through the [commands manual](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/commands_manual.html) and have not found this.

Comment: List of datanodes is available via namenode's JMX interface -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/44069584/1097572

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use the [dfsadmin command](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/commands_manual.html#dfsadmin):

`bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report`

Update (2015):

`bin/hdfs dfsadmin -report`

Comment: OK what I don't get is why my namenode only reports itself as a datanode, and none of the datanodes I listed in `slaves` file show up in `dfsadmin -report`

Comment: On the namenode url (http://<IP of namenode>:50070/dfshealth.jsp), see if the other nodes are dead / decomissioned. Also, watch the datanode logs to identify the problem

Comment: This command is now deprecated: `DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.`

Answer (score 35):

Try this:

```
hdfs getconf -namenodes
hdfs getconf -secondaryNamenodes
```

Answer (score 26):

Try This. For dfsadmin not every user has permission.

> ```
> hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS
> hdfs://XYZ
> ```

Answer (score 5):

2016 *update*, following Tejas answer:

```
hadoopuser@gsamaras:~/hadoop/bin$ ./hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
hdfs getconf -namenodes
hdfs getconf -secondaryNamenodes
```

Work only non-HA mode.
The simplest way for HA-mode is to use:

```bash
hdfs haadmin -getAllServiceState
```

haadmin work for HA mode.

Output:

```bash
hadoop-adh-1:8020                standby
hadoop-adh-2:8020                active
```