# Rest Api for getting dfs used for individual nodes in hadoop

Tags: rest, hadoop, hdfs

Is there any rest API or Hadoop metrics for getting dfs used for individual nodes. Currently, I'm getting dfs used for individual nodes by executing the below command manually

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a REST API but you should be able to use the NameNode's JMX interface to pull this info.

```
http://NAMENODE:DFSPORT/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeInfo
```

This contains the same information as:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

which is also published on:

```
http://NAMENODE:DFSPORT/dfshealth.html#tab-datanode
```